# Printing jsf ArrayLIst via Jasper Report using JRBeanCollectionDataSource

Tags: jsf, jasper-reports

I'm using a jsf array list to retrieve records based on some criteria. Now I want contents of this array list to be print via Jasper report. I followed following steps.

1. Used empty datasource in Jasper report.
2. Created Fields in jasper reports as those of my bean properties.
3. Then I compiled the report to ***employeeList.jasper*** and placed that in my ***/reports
       /employeeReports/employeeList.jasper*** folder in jsf project (I'm using Eclipse).

I have then used following code to fill and show the pdf report

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(this.srchdEmployeesList);
try {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response =
            (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    HashMap parameterMap = new HashMap();
    JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("/reports/employeeReports/employeeList.jasper", parameterMap, dataSource);
    InputStream reportStream = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/reports/employessReports/employeeList.jasper");
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Session hibernateSession = null;
    hibernateSession = HibernateUtils.currentSession();
    connection = hibernateSession.connection();
    facesContext.responseComplete();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;");
    JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream, parameterMap, connection);

    connection.close();
    servletOutputStream.flush();
    servletOutputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I recieve following error message and report do not show up

```
  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \reports
  \employeeReports\employeeList.jasper
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \reports\employeeReports
   \employeeList.jasper ... 34 more
```

Help in this regard would be highly appreciated. Bundles of thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of JasperReports API are you using? You should read the javadoc for `JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile` method better: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html#fillReportToFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map,%20net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource%29

Comment: thnks Alex. i want to know, is there some thing logically wrong with my code. any ways, i am using JasperReports 4.1.1.

Comment: i read the javadoc, it says fillReportToFile(java.lang.String sourceFileName,java.lang.String destFileName...) i did used second argument like this...JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("/reports/employeeReports/employeeList.jasper","/reports/employeeReports/employeeList.jasper",parameterMap, dataSource), but i am getting exactly same error.

Comment: Did you check the existence of the file with help of java code? May be the problem in file location (path to the file)

Comment: Alex. i have compiled the jasper file and its in the Web Content/reports/employeeReports/employeeList. it is there. so then why is it throwing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that the report is in "Web Content/reports/employeeReports/employeeList". But your code doesn't seem to point there. Your code points to "/reports/employeeReports/employeeList.jasper".

Is it as simple as using a relative path?
"reports/employeeReports/employeeList.jasper" or "./reports/employeeReports/employeeList.jasper"

Comment: i used "/reports/employeeReports/employeeList.jasper", "./reports/employeeReports/employeeList.jasper", "../reports/employeeReports/employeeList.jasper", "reports/employeeReports/employeeList.jasper" but it gives the same net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: